# Withdrawing ethereum from a smart contract (return to sender)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, ether, truffle

Let's say I have a decentralized application that allows people to buy some object at an arbitrary price.

User 1 purchases the object for 1 eth. A few moments later, user 2 purchases the same item. How can I monitor for this event and automatically return the appropriate amount of etherium to user 2? Here's what I have so far:

```
contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    function returnEth() public payable {
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
    }
    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        //require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
        returnEth();
        return petId;
        //return value;
    }
    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
        return adopters;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your second question is unrelated to the first. I'd suggest asking it as a new question. (It's hard for others to benefit from your question or answer it if it's buried inside another question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, I think you're saying that user 2 shouldn't be allowed to purchase the item that user 1 already purchased.

If that's the case, then the call user 2 made to purchase the item should fail. You haven't shared the function that is used to make a purchase, but it should revert the transaction if the item is already sold.

Comment: What happens if the transaction is still being confirmed?

Comment: A transaction that hasn't been confirmed is just waiting around. It doesn't have any effect. When it finally gets processed, it will either succeed (if it's the first to buy the item) or fail.

Comment: That's good information, but I'd still like to know how to send ether to users from the contract. Should I update my original question?

Comment: It's just `<address>.transfer(<amount>)`.

Comment: So would my original code theoretically work, if it was called at the right time?

Comment: For your original code, if User A sends 1 ether to the function, then it transfers 1 ether to User A. If for some reason you don't want to just revert the transaction, then this seems like a fine way to refund the transferred ether.

Comment: okay. If I wanted to call that function inside of my contract (it's the same one as the one you replied to on my last question), how would I do that with web3js? I just don't want to spam StackExchange with questions.

Comment: To call it from another function in your contract, just do `returnEth();`. If your question is "How do I call a function from web3.js?" that doesn't seem related. Please ask it as a new question, but first, please just read a tutorial, maybe even mine: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/. (I think, though, that maybe you're using Truffle? If so, look at a tutorial for that instead.)

Comment: so I won't talk about the web3js thing anymore, but if I call returnEth(); in my existing contract, eth is deducted from my metamask wallet but it is not returned. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: No. Directly calling `returnEth()` should never reduce the amount of ether in the caller's account. Even if the `transfer` fails, the transaction will be reverted, so no ether will move.

Comment: 1 eth is deducted from their wallet from the adopt() function in my previous question. returnEth() is called from within adopt(), but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You'd have to share the actual code you're using (I guess the current code for `adopt` that calls `returnEth`.)

Comment: updated my question with the full code

Comment: The code in your question works fine for me. Note that gas fees apply no matter what, so the account's ether balance should go down a tiny amount with each transaction. But if I start with 100 ether and send 1 ether to `adopt()`, I end up with >99.99999999 ether after the call.